# Enabling HTTPS over a WCF Service on IIS

Tags: wcf, web-services, ssl, https, web-config

Asking this question again in stack overflow seems stupid as there are enough posts already on this topic...but i can see that every post has its own way of achieving this..So my config file is specified here below...I have followed up all the relevant posts and wrote this Web config file..But after all efforts also i get this error below :

**"Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]."**

Here is my Web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="WcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ReqServiceBehaviour">
                <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
                <endpoint address="files" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
                                bindingConfiguration="httpStreamingBinding" name="UploadEndpoint"
                                contract="WcfService.IService1" />
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="WcfService.IService1"/>

                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>

        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="httpStreamingBinding" transferMode="Streamed" />
            </webHttpBinding>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ReqServiceBehaviour">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>

            </endpointBehaviors>

        </behaviors>

        <protocolMapping>

            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: ***ANY HELP ON SOLVING THIS ERROR AND ENABLING HTTPS OVER WCF IS APPRECIATED !!! THANKS IN ADVANCE !!*** deleted, not good in answer, @praveengodfrey

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try following

In order to use https, you require to set httpsGetEnabled="true" instead of httpGetEnabled="true"